# Plotting a function and finding its limit as $x \to \infty$

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I have been giving the problem of finding the limit of a function as $x \to \infty$. I also want to plot the function over a large range.

I don't have an issue in finding the limit, but I'm having trouble with plotting.

> Problem statement
>
> What do you say is the limiting value of $f(x) = ((x^9 + 4e^{(.6x)})/(3x^{12} + 2e^{(.6x)}))$ when $x\to\infty$?

This is my code.

```
Clear[f, x]
f[x_] = ((x^9 + 4e^(.6x))/(3x^12 + 2e^(.6x)))
l = Limit[f[x], x -> infinity]
Plot[f[x], {x, -1000000, 1000000}]​
```

I keep getting an error.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for $exp()$ is `Exp[]` not `exp()` and `Infinity` not `infinity`.

```
Clear[f, x]

f[x_] = ((x^9 + 4 Exp[.6 x])/(3 x^12 + 2 Exp[(.6 x)]));

l = Limit[f[x], x -> Infinity]
```

> 2

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10^5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

​[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I realized it had to be a syntax issue, and thank you for solving this!